# Trouble positioning multiple images and scaling down images

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am having trouble positioning my images in the bottom and center of the page. I have managed to get the images to be at the bottom of the page but i cannot get the images to be in the center. Also when i resize the browser the images all stack up on each other. How would i get the images to resize as the browser shrinks in size. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>A-level Revision Website</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="banner">
        <h1>A-Level Revision Website</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <form id="loginForm">
            <input type="email" class="login-username" autofocus="true" required="true" placeholder="Email" /><br>
            <input type="password" class="login-password" required="true" placeholder="Password" /><br>
            <input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login" class="login-submit" /><br>
            <a href="#" class="login-forgot-pass">forgot password?</a>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="imagesMain">
        <a href="Maths.html">
            <img src="images/Maths.jpg" alt="Maths"">
        </a>
        <a href="ComputerScience.html">  
            <img src="images/Computer_Science.jpg" alt="ComputerScience">
        </a>
        <a href="Physics.html">  
            <img src="images/Physics.jpg" alt="Physics"">
        </a>
    </div>
</html>

.banner{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #595959;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 180px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
}

#imagesMain{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 20px 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

body, html {   
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display:table;
}
body {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
form {
    display:table;
    margin:auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zntzep48/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per your code, to align images properly style `#imagesMain a` like follows to resize images as per browser width

```
#imagesMain a{
  width:30%;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  margin:1.5%;
}

#imagesMain {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 600px;//change this value to fit as you want
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 20px auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zntzep48/7/)(updated)

Comment: The scaling is working great but when in full screen the images are a little to far spaced out, any way to change that?

Comment: updated my answer in that `#imagesMain ` change `max-width` property as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fixed` on place of `absolute` and tweak some of the other css properties as shown below:

```
#imagesMain{
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
padding: 0;
margin: 20px auto;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
}


img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 25px;
    position:relative;
}
```

Edit: Adding [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zntzep48/6/)

Edit2: You can make reference to [fiddle1](https://jsfiddle.net/zntzep48/8/) for media queries

Comment: My images are centered perfectly but the images are still overlapping each other when the browser shrinks, any way to scale down the images as the browser resizes?

Comment: you have to play with image width and media queries